# Nodes placed on tikz lines inherit manystyles but not "double"

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using tikz, When nodes are placed on styled lines, and drawn, they inherit that line's styles (dotted, dashed, color, thickness) but NOT the double style.

[image: double style is not inherited]

```
\draw[green] (0,2) -- node[draw, fill=white] {X} ++(3,0);
\draw[dotted] (0,1.5) -- node[draw, fill=white] {X} ++(3,0);
\draw[line width=.2ex] (0,1) -- node[draw, fill=white] {X} ++(3,0);
% this fails :
\draw[double] (0,0) -- node[draw, fill=white] {X} ++(3,0);
% node has to be styled specifically :
\draw[double] (0,-1) -- node[draw, fill=white, double] {X} ++(3,0);
```

Is there a way to get this done ?

Comment: You could define your own style. `\begin{tikzpicture}[Double/.style={double,nodes={double}}]
\draw[Double] (0,0) -- node[draw, fill=white] {X} ++(3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Didn't now of the "nodes" style, I'm definitally going to use it. Perfect ! Could you turn it into an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is correct. You can fix this by defining a new style, `Double`, which takes care of the nodes. `nodes` is a shorthand for `every node/.append style`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Double/.style={double,nodes={double}}]
\draw[Double] (0,0) -- node[draw, fill=white] {X} ++(3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The effect of the key is limited to the path in which you use it, which is probably what you want.